# Error while using Geolocation API with CURL to fetch latitude and longitude

Tags: php, curl

Using the below curl code, we can fetch latitude and longitude, but it is giving error:

```
<?php
  $requestbody=array("considerIp"=>"false");
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, 
  CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$requestbody);
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  echo $result;
  ?>
```

Error:
{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Not Found", "errors": [ { "message": "Not Found", "domain": "geolocation", "reason": "notFound" } ] } }

Reference link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview

Could you please help me solve this error:

Comment: You are not passing _any_ data to specify what location you want lat/long for here to begin with, so what result would you expect it to find?

Comment: Please include the required parameters in the body as mentioned in the reference link